# Is it possible to make restartPolicy never during a kubernetes deployment, but only during the deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

Whenever I do a Kubernetes deployment with some sort of configuration error, the pod ends up in CrashLoopBackOff, constantly restarting the (totally broken) pod. What I would like is for any sort of errors during a deployment to immediately fail the deployment, rather than just blindly retrying until the deployment times out.

Answer (score 2):

Deploy with `restartPolicy: never` and then use [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#kubectl-patch) to modify the restart policy of that deployment.

To avoid continuous restart attempt of failing pod there is one open [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49466).

Also there is one open [pull request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/79334) to add this feature which is about to get merged, where you will have ability to specify max retries for restart policy OnFailure.

Till this feature get merged and released, `kubectl patch` seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can first deploy your cluster with `restartPolicy: never`, then use [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#kubectl-patch) to modify the restart policy of the running deployment.